# How does the output register data path work in the 6502?

Tags: processor, 6502

I am currently developing a subset of the 6502 in LogiSim and at the current stage I am determining which parts to implement and what can be cut out. One of my main resources is [Hanson's Block Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxwKp.jpg).

I am currently trying to determine how exactly the output register and its data path works. In this diagram, it looks to me like the data output register goes back onto the bus through the Input Data Latch, but also back into the instruction register.

[image: Confusing part of diagram]

This confuses me because usually the Address lines to the right of the diagram are sent back into the program memory (not pictured) and not back onto the bus as pictured.

How exactly does this data path work? As a follow up, Is it possible to simplify this area to only take the output and send it to a display instead of back into the processor as pictured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This confuses me because usually the Address lines to the right of the diagram are sent back into the program memory (not pictured) and not back onto the bus as pictured.

The address bus works differently from the data bus. The address bus is *always* Output, but the data bus can be Input or Output. We say that the databus is tristate; it either reads, or writes, or does neither. Each pin `d0` thru `d7` has a simple circuit involving a couple of transistors that controls this. In the case of the 6502, each and every cycle the CPU is either reading something or writing something. In other words, from the 6502's point of view, every cycle is either a read or write cycle.

> I am currently trying to determine how exactly the output register and its data path works.

Have a look: the Input Data Latch and Predecode Register are loaded with *each φ2*. But the Output Data Register is loaded with *each φ1*. φ1 and φ2 are the two phases of the CPU clock. This arrangement leaves enough time for, say a value to pass from the Input Data Latch, through the ALU, and into the Output Data Register for example.

The Data Output Register's output goes to the Data Bus Tristate Buffers. As you can see, that is controlled by `R/W` and also by `φ2`.  If it's a read cycle, nothing happens there. So if it's a write cycle, that means the value in the Data Output Register (which was loaded with the previous φ1) is going to be put onto the databus. It also will get loaded into the Predecode Register and into the Input Data Latch.

> In this diagram, it looks to me like the data output register goes back onto the bus through the Input Data Latch, but also back into the instruction register.

Absolutely. Anything that the CPU outputs could also get loaded into the Input Data Latch and the Predecode Register. But that doesn't matter, since an instruction will always start with a read cycle, which is the opcode fetch, so the Input Data Latch and the Predecode Register will get overwritten then with the proper value.